# JQuery's append alternative/JavaScript (append element to canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to figure out how can I append this with pure JavaScript? I've tried with the DOM equivalent but maybe I can't write it properly. This is about to be a chess board grid.

```
divString = "<div class=\"Square " + rankName + " " + fileName + " " + lightString + "\"/>";

$("#Board").append(divString); // <= How can I append this to the canvas with pure JavaScript?

<canvas id="board" width="480" height="480" style="border: solid 1px Black;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Don't think you can add html elements to a canvas.

Comment: You can't append HTML to a canvas, but you can include HTML in an SVG format and render that instead.  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas) covers how to do this

Comment: You can append to the canvas but it is not displayed if the canvas tag is supported. Eg `<canvas><div>Not supported</div></canvas>`

Comment: It says: "TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object."